# >: expects a real, given (void)

Tags: racket, computer-science

I am currently struggling with creating a list that finds if all the numbers within the list are equal to each other:

```
(define (list-all-equal lon) (cond [(empty? lon) lon]
                                  [(empty? (rest lon)) (first lon)]
                                  [(empty? (rest (rest lon))) (first lon)]
                                  [(equal? (first lon) (list-all-equal(rest lon))) (write #true)]
                                  [(> (first lon) (list-all-equal(rest lon))) (write #false)]
                                  [(< (first lon) (list-all-equal(rest lon))) (write #false)]
                                  [else (list-all-equal (rest lon))]))
```

However, I keep on receiving the error: `>: expects a real, given void`. is there a way to solve the error?

Comment: Notice that it doesn't make sense to compare if the current number is less-than or greater-than other number. It's enough to ask if it's equal or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `write` as part of the recursion, and `write` "returns" `void`, which will lead to something like this:

```
(> some-number (void))
```

Never use `write` to return a value from your procedures! We want to *return* the results, not to *display* them on the console. And for this case you have to implement your procedure in such a way that, if it finds a different number, it stops comparing - the result is false and we shouldn't continue. A good strategy would be to pass along the first element and compare the rest against it:

```
(define (list-all-equal lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      #t
      (list-all-equal-helper (first lst) (rest lst))))

(define (list-all-equal-helper ele lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) #t)
        ((not (= (first lst) ele)) #f)
        (else (list-all-equal-helper ele (rest lst)))))
```

Or, we could use `apply` :)

```
(define (list-all-equal lst)
  (apply = lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(list-all-equal '(1 2 3))
=> #f
(list-all-equal '(1 1 1))
=> #t
```

Answer (score 1):

`write` does not return a value, so when you compare to the recursive result you're going to end up comparing to "nothing".

Also, your function should return `#true` or `#false`, not list elements, and comparing list elements to the results of recursing does not make much sense.

I think you started writing code before solving the problem.
A helpful way to start is with listing the possibilities.

- All elements of an empty list are equal
- All elements of a singleton list are equal
- If the list has at least two elements, and the first element is equal to the second element, all the elements are equal if and only if all elements in its tail are equal
- Otherwise, there is at least one unequal element

Translated:

```
(define (list-all-equal lon) 
    (cond [(empty? lon) #true]
          [(empty? (rest lon)) #true]
          [(equal? (first lon) (second lon)) (list-all-equal (rest lon))]
          [else #false]))
```

Comment: Interesting, I would have never thought of listing the possibilities down. Thank you for the amazing advice and help XD.